# Infinite loop in Terminal (ksh) to launch commands

Tags: command-line, terminal, shell, ksh

I'm trying to create a loop in terminal to launch every second during the execution of an script the following command. I don't want to create the loop in `.sh` script file, i'm trying to do in the prompt.

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
for 1
> do
> ls -ltr
> date
> sleep 2
> done
```

Error message: `ksh: 1: is not an identifier`

I'm using korn shell in AIX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
while true 
do 
   ls -ltr
   date 
   sleep 2 
done
```

The above can be broken with Ctrl-C

A single line:

```
while true; do ls -ltr; date; sleep 2; done
```